# How can i force a filled form to be open directly ReadyOnly mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, display-form, read-only

I have a SharePoint list. People can fill the form and submit that form to the list. I created a calculated column with the code below. This code générated a link in the list. Once people click on the link generated , it should open the form filled in Read Only mode. But actually, it is not the case. I would like to know how can I force the form to open in ReadOnly mode once users click on the link. Here's the code:                                                                                       ---

```
="<a target='_blank'  href=https://MyWebSite.MyDomain.com/SiteName/_layouts/Print.FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/cours/MyList/ItemNum%20no%20"&RequestNumber&".xml&ClientInstalled=false&Source=http%3A%2F%2FMyWebSite%2EMyDomain%2Ecom%2FMySiteName%2FMyList%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1><DisplayRequest</a>"
```

Comment: Hi @djqibbs are you using infopath ?

Comment: Hi M. Qassas  yes i am using InfoPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any option that will let you open InfoPath form as read-only directly ,

But you can achieve this by

- Designing a read-only view and
- Set the URL to point to this view by adding `&DefaultView=yourviewname` to your Link.

To do this follow the mentioned steps below :

- On the View menu, click Manage Views.
- Under Actions, click Add a New View.
- In the Add View dialog box, type a name for the view, and then click OK.
- Design the view by adding layout tables and controls to it.

**TIP:** If you want to base the design of a new view on an existing view, open the existing view, press CTRL+A to select everything in the view, and then press CTRL+C to copy the selection to the Clipboard. In the Views task pane, switch to the new view, and then press CTRL+V to paste the selection in the new view. At this point, you can delete any controls or layout elements that you don't need from the new view.

- In the Views task pane, click View Properties.
- Click the General tab.
- Under View settings, select the `Read-only` check box, and then click OK.

For more details check [Design a read-only view](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Design-a-read-only-view-d11396da-14b8-4c6d-84c3-5e48399b8d99#bm1)

**Then** in your URL specify `&DefaultView=yourviewname` to your link before or after`&DefaultItemOpen=1`

Comment: Thankyou a lot Qassas. It works.

Comment: Glad to hear it's helped you, could you please upvote it :)